# Jquery scroll to element position due position:fixed element

Tags: jquery, position, fixed, scrollto, calculation

I need to make simple thing - scroll to element after click on button.
But I can't understand what happens after click.
I think reason of problem header which made 'position:fixed' after scrolldown.
Click to right button "Scroll to Element" must be scroll to Element, but it must be appear after fixed header.
First click to "Scroll to Element" goes to wrong position, but another one click made correct view.

```
[https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JyBrWd][1]
```

Comment: http://help.typepad.com/anchor-tags.html You should use local anchors. There's no need at all to use javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i think anchors can't help me. See https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dzjaav